# Move (Cut&Paste) Powerpoint Slides with Sections information by VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a solution to select some slides and cut or copy and paste at another location while keeping the section information.
I have seen PPT does not support it out of the box (see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-powerpoint/copying-sections-to-a-new-powerpoint/2c723b0d-d465-4ab6-b127-6fdfc195478c?db=5)
and also some VBA Script examples here [Exporting PowerPoint sections into separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707249/exporting-powerpoint-sections-into-separate-files)
PPTalchemy provides some Add-In but unfortunately the code is not available. See here http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/powerpoint_hints_and_tips_tutorials.html#2010

Moreover it does not suit to move sections easily within the same presentation.

Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks.
Thierry

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when pasting to a different slide index position? If pasting within a section, there's nothing to do (AFAIK but need to check) but if pasting to another section are you expecting a new section to be created with the same name as the source section? What's the actual need of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Good question. What I am trying to achieve is to move multiple sections (with all their belonging slides) around. I would do this in a "Collapse all" sections view or paste just before the section before the selection. I want to be able to reorganize my presentation this way. Imagine I have Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, Part 4, Part 5 sections in my presentation, and I want to change its logic/ structure to Part 1, Part 4, Part 5, Part 2, Part 3. I would in this case "move" Part 4 and Part 5 after Part 1 or before Part 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is finally the [code](https://gist.github.com/tdalon/c25b2e71553217599b95f9f631316732) I use to move multiple sections selected by slides:

```
Sub MoveSelectedSections()
' Slides are copied ready to be pasted
Dim lngNewPosition As Long
'Debug.Print ""
'Debug.Print "###Move Sections..."
lngNewPosition = InputBox("Enter a destination section index:")
lngNewPosition = CInt(lngNewPosition) ' Convert String to Int
Call MoveSectionsSelectedBySlides(ActivePresentation, lngNewPosition)

End Sub


Function MoveSectionsSelectedBySlides(oPres As Presentation, lNewPosition As Long)
  On Error GoTo errorhandler

  ' Activate input presentation
  oPres.Windows(1).Activate

  ' Get Selected Sections Indexes

  ' http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/3/copy-selected-slides-into-new-powerpoint-presentation

    Dim i, cnt As Integer
    Dim SelectedSlides As SlideRange
    Dim SectionIndexes() As Long

    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionSlides Then
        MsgBox "No slides selected"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set SelectedSlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
    ' selection order is reverse see http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00869_Create_a_custom_show_from_current_slide_selection_using_VBA.htm


  'Fill an array with sectionIndex numbers
    ReDim SectionIndexes(1 To SelectedSlides.Count)
    cnt = 0
    For i = 1 To SelectedSlides.Count
    ' Check if already present in array
      If Not Contains(SectionIndexes, SelectedSlides(i).sectionIndex) Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        SectionIndexes(cnt) = SelectedSlides(i).sectionIndex
      End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve SectionIndexes(1 To cnt)


    ' Move Sections to lNewPosition,  first last
    For i = 1 To cnt
        With oPres
          .SectionProperties.Move SectionIndexes(i), lNewPosition
        End With
        Debug.Print "Section #" & SectionIndexes(i) & " moved to " & lNewPosition
    Next i



Exit Function
errorhandler:
  Debug.Print "Couldn't move section due to the following error: " & Err & ", " & Err.Description
End Function





Function Contains(arr, v) As Boolean
' http://stackoverflow.com/a/18769246/2043349
Dim rv As Boolean, i As Long ' Default value of boolean is False
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i) = v Then
       rv = True
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
Contains = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

To move a section within a presentation, including all slides within the section, call this procedure with the index of the section to be moved and it's new location:

```
Option Explicit

' ********************************************************************************
' VBA Macro for PowerPoint, written by Jamie Garroch of http://YOUpresent.co.uk/
' ********************************************************************************
' Purpose : Moves a specified section of slides to a new section location
' Inputs  : lSectionIndex - the index of the section to be moved
'           lNewPosition - the index of the position to move to
' Outputs : None.
' ********************************************************************************
Public Sub MoveSection(lSectionIndex As Long, lNewPosition As Long)
  On Error GoTo errorhandler
  With ActivePresentation
    .SectionProperties.Move lSectionIndex, lNewPosition
  End With
Exit Sub
errorhandler:
  Debug.Print "Couldn't move section due to the following error: " & Err & ", " & Err.Description
End Sub
```